# Selenium SendKeys (Keys.PageDown); how to make a click one-time

Tags: c#, selenium

I am writing tests in C # and selenium, but the sendkeys (Keys.PageDown) command manages to work several times, but I need one input.

```
IWebElement ledgerCreateFolder = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select [@data-val-number = 'The field id_fp_ledger_parent must be a number.']"));
Thread.Sleep(500);
ledgerCreateFolder.Click();
Thread.Sleep(500);
ledgerCreateFolder.SendKeys(Keys.PageDown);
Thread.Sleep(500);
ledgerCreateFolder.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
Thread.Sleep(1500);
```

Comment: would you mind clarifying what do you mean by "manages to work several times"?

Comment: Oh yeah.
I have a list, I need to select the first row from it.
But the command "SendKeys (Keys.PageDown);" sends PageDown multiple times.
Therefore, the last row is selected from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to select the row directly using XPath? In that case you wouldn't need to use PageDown, what matters is if it shows in the html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).